# Dynamically Change Identity Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have an asp.net application which I am in the process of moving away from my historic custom authentication and migrating to asp.net Identity Framework.

It is a cloud based solution and previously when a user logged in, it was getting the connection string from a generic database after a lookup using the domain name.

However, once I have got the correct database name, how can I use this with Identity, as this is where the connection string is defined:

```
 public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("MyConStringHere", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
```

Currently I have a method which returns a connection string depending on the customers database:

```
  return new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

But I was calling this before by passing the database name in my application, I am unsure how I can use this in the ApplicationDbContext()

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if a got the question right, but you can surely use your connectionstring on your ApplicationDbContext constructor. For example: my ctx = new ApplicationDbContext(connectionString);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass your connection string from your configurations:

```
 public ApplicationDbContext(string myClientConnectionString)
        : base(myClientConnectionString, throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
```

This is what I use in multi-tenanted application.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! How do you then pass the connectrionstring to it? I have tried in Startup.Auth.cs but it I create a new instance does not have a create method? Perhaps I am miss-understanding how to call this part

Comment: If you are building multi-tenanted application, your bes bet would be to use Dependency Injection container that by some parameter (url?) decides what tenant you are working with, somehow gets the related connection string from the storage and initiates your `dbContext` with the correct database. And you don't use OWIN to do that - it is not designed for your purpose. I suggest you lookup DI containers with multi-tenancy and open another question with more details - once you stumble.

Comment: Good thought, do you mean by giving the user a unique url for there instance for example rather than let the web application determine it? Thanks

Comment: It depends on what you are doing, there is no definite rule about this one. If you are planning a custom domain-names then yes - your tenants are defined by domain-names. If not, then your tenants are defined when users are logged-in and they get a `tenantId` added to their auth cookie as a `Claim`. I can see both scenarios working equally well.